# Not able to select any element from chosen dropdown having hidden attribute using testNG Selenium 3.3.1 in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have tried different ways, but not able to get any success. Please help me to find some solution for this problem.

I am testing an application having a page like [this](https://www.marstranslation.com/place-order).
Please refer to this page and help me to select values from dropdown given above page.

**BTW with the help of following lines, I am able to click on dropdown, but then not able to select any value using different techniques.**

```
WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#step_language > div.well.well-lg > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.mars_chosen_container.clearfix"));
source.click();
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You write you are "able to click on the dropdown, but then not select any value". How do you "select the value"? And what happens then? Please add the code you have, the result you expect and what actually happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.

```
driver.get("https://www.marstranslation.com/place-order");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/span[contains(text(), 'English')]")).click();          //Click on dropdown using xpath locator.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);    //Use explicit wait method for find an element
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[contains(text(), 'Arabic')]"))));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[contains(text(), 'Arabic')]")).click();      //After explicit wait, click on Arabic option from dropdown using xpath locator.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
    WebElement TargetLanguage =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#targetLanguageId_chosen>ul>li>input"));
    TargetLanguage.click();

    Thread.sleep(3000);

    // Gets the target languages in the List
    List<WebElement> LangElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#targetLanguageId_chosen>.chosen-drop>ul>li"));
    for(WebElement t : LangElements)
    {
        if(t.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Arabic"))
        {
            t.click();
        }

    }
```

Here as an example I clicked on *Arabic*. You can replace the same with your required language and use it.

Hope it works for you. If anything goes wrong please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to write functions for things like this since they will likely be reused.

```
public static void SelectSourceLanguage(String language)
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.chosen-single")).click(); // click the dropdown
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='chosen-results']/li[contains(.,'" + language + "')]")).click(); // click the language
}
```

Then you can call it like

```
driver.get("https://www.marstranslation.com/place-order");
SelectSourceLanguage("Hindi");
```